# Logout pop up to come in all tabs in same time

Tags: php, jquery, settimeout

Suppose a user can use their account for 60 minutes without any inactivity. And, in 58 minutes, need to show one alert pop up by saying "*Your system is about to logout. Press OK to be logged-in*".

**main.js**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //Auto Logout
    autoLogoutPopUp(auto_logout_time);
    automaticallyLogout(logout_time);
});

function autoLogoutPopUp(time){
    setTimeout(function(){showAutoLogoutPopUp();}, time);
}

function automaticallyLogout(time){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "logout";
    }, time);
}
```

What's happening right now is. For one tab, it's OK. It's working fine. But, when multiple tabs are opened, If I press OK in one Tab. It still get logout from another tab (which is due to `$(window).load(function() {});` in **main.js** file which get executed for all the tabs resulting different time  set for that particular tab). How to show that particular logout pop up for all the tabs in the same time?

I tried using local storage. But, was unable to achieve it. Any help/hint/suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Use `websockets` (or equivalent) and store the timeout on the server, either by session or by user.  Then when they're active on one tab it will update the end-time on the server.

Comment: Ultimately, each tab will create a new timeout function so unless you start them all at the same time, I don't think they would ever trigger at the same time without persisting a common time between all of them i.e. server side time.  So you're gonna have to do some rework since you're storing the time on the client side and not the server side.  It will be a completely different design from the one you have now, i.e. constant AJAX requests on the client-side and time checking on the server side.

Comment: Yes. I'm now trying that too. let's see how it goes. Thanks @freedomn-m

Comment: Thanks @cchoe1. Actually, from last 3-4 hours, I'm spending my time to find out one global solution for this problem. But, every time, I stuck finding new topics. `:D`. Let me try by storing the values in server side. Will get back.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the local storage idea, how about setting a "Reset Logout Timer" value whenever the user clicks "OK" and then using event listeners to detect the change and reset the timers? You'd have to store the timeout handle to reset it later.

Something like:

```
var popupTimerHandle;
var logoutTimerHandle;

// When the local storage data gets changed, clear the existing timer and recreate it
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event){
    if (event.key == 'reset-logout-timer') { 
        window.clearTimeout(popupTimerHandle);
        window.clearTimeout(logoutTimerHandle);

        AutoLogoutPopUp(auto_logout_time);
        AutomaticallyLogout(logout_time);
    }
});

function AutomaticallyLogout(time){
    logoutTimerHandle = setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "logout";
    }, time);
}

function AutoLogoutPopUp(time){
    popupTimerHandle = setTimeout(function(){showAutoLogoutPopUp();}, time);
}

// Called when the user clicks "OK" to stay logged in.
// The value doesn't matter as long as the change is registered
function TriggerLogoutTimerReset() {
    localStorage.setItem('reset-logout-timer', Math.random());
}
```

Comment: Hi @yoten, thanks for answering. Answer looks promising, but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Which part isn't working? Take a look at this JSFiddle (open it in multiple tabs): https://jsfiddle.net/cga8me8y/5/